Low Side Switching a PC
I made a PCB that takes 12V power in and passes it to the output connector, except the GND connection on the output has a low-side switching circuit through an N-channel MOSFET. The gate of the MOSFET connects to an ESP32 microcontroller, that should be able to power cycle the PC that's connected to the forementioned output connector (this computer is powered with 12V DC). This is made as a watchdog solution to restart the computer in case it's unresponsive

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When I connect the computer, everything works as expected, and I can power it down by pulling the gate low.
However, I noticed some unusual behavior when the computer has a HDMI/DP connected to the monitor. When connecting a video cable, the low-side switching is now unable to cut the power from the computer.
In my last test, I disconnected the negative power terminal (the one going to the NMOS, see schematic below) from the power jack all together, so now the PC is only connected to the board with a +12v connection and power loop is incomplete. However, if I plug in an HDMI (or DP), the PC boots up.
Does this mean that the PC is creating a huge current loop between my board (and it's power supply), the monitor, the monitor's power supply, and the AC grid?

If that's true, the solution I'm thinking of is to use high-side switching instead of low-side switching, since it seems like I have little to no control on the low-side when a video cable is connected. Are there any ways to solve it with low-side switching?
EDIT:
I found that for the PC to work without the negative barrel jack connection, the PC has to have an HDMI connected AND I need to connect a USB from the board to my PC. The USB is connected to a CP2104 USB-UART bridge, and the GND is connected to a GND plane on the board

The PS used is OWA-90U-20-P1M by Meanwell. The AC plug on it is non-grounded
Here is a rough block diagram of the connections


What is your power supply?

@TimWilliams It's a regulated power supply from Meanwell. The actual input is 20V and is being converted with a SEPIC converter down to 12V. (I omitted those details for the sake of simplicity)

Please show the part number and how it's connected (mains input wiring and output terminals), and how the SEPIC is wired.

Low side switching anything with connections to some other thing is generally a bad idea.
Your power supply seems to connect the GND return terminal to mains PE wire, and if the power supply of the monitor does the exact same thing, you are using the HDMI cable and mains PE as the GND return path for the PC supply.
Simply be happy that it went through so good path of conduction and connectors that connect ground first. Image few extra amp throug some data cable like USB which might have gotten old and scratchy so there wouls be 12V and few amps through data wires instead if the ground connection were intermittent while plugging it it.
There are ways around that, but literally every desktop PC connects the mains PE to the GND for example, and hot-plugging floating supplies between devices can damage devices, so the best option is to simply switch the high side.
If you just want to virtually push the reset or soft power buttons of the PC, the microcontroller can do that too so you don't need low or high side switching.
EDIT: with th new info that the power supply has no PE, it went throuh another route. Your board connects USB to some other PC, and it goes throug that path. Current goes in a loop.

Thank you for confirming my suspicion!
Using a reset button on a PC would make a lot of sense generally, but in my situation this board would be used with multiple different computer models, and we don't necessarily want to dig into the enclosure to get access to the pins for resetting.
Would you say high-side switching is my way to go in these circumstances?

@Denis Actually with the updated info, my answer is now wrong - it can't go through power supply PE wire if it has none!

I think it loops fully within the DC realm. One thing i didn't mention is that this monitor is connected to both computers on src1 and src2. Hence it likely connects the DC grounds between the two computers, which is also connected to the PCB GND and the 20V negative side.
I am now quite certain that high-side switching should be solution here
